# Error Json deserialization and List<>

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON response. With simple response I've no problem but with a complex response I get this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APIEffilogics.Usuari+Node]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

It seems that I have a problem with the type of I put when deserialize the string. The JSON string is like this:

```
{

        nodes: [
          {
            id: 5,
            global_id: 5,
            description: "Oven",
            room_id: 2,
            floor_id: 1,
            building_id: 1,
            client_id: 2,
            nodemodel_id: 2,
            nodetype_id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 39,
            global_id: 39,
            description: "Fridge",
            room_id: 2,
            floor_id: 1,
            building_id: 1,
            client_id: 2,
            nodemodel_id: 8,
            nodetype_id: 1
          }, ...
        ],
        limit: 10,
        offset: 0
    }
```

And those are the classes:

```
public class Node : Usuari      //Estructura nodes
{            
   [JsonProperty("limit")]
   public int limit { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("offset")]
   public int offset { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("nodes")]
   public List<Node_sub> nodes_sub { get; set; }
}
public class Node_sub : Node
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string nid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("global_id")]
    public string gid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string descrip { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("room_id")]
    public string rid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("floor_id")]
    public string fid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("client_id")]
    public string cid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("building_id")]
    public string bid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("nodemodel_id")]
    public string model { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("nodetype_id")]
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

The code is:

```
public void Request(string url, string metode, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                //Enviem la petició a la URL especificada i configurem el tipus de connexió
                HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                myReq.KeepAlive = true;
                myReq.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "no-store");
                myReq.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache");
                myReq.Headers.Set("Authorization", usuari.token_type + " " + usuari.access_token);
                myReq.ContentType = "application/json";

                if (metode.Equals("GET") || metode.Equals("POST"))
                {
                    myReq.Method = metode;  // Set the Method property of the request to POST or GET.
                    if (body == true)
                    {
                        // add request body with chat search filters
                        List<paramet> p = new List<paramet>();
                        paramet p1 = new paramet();
                        p1.value = "1";
                        string jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
                        var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonBody);
                        myReq.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
                        //myReq.ContentType = "application/json";
                        using (var stream = myReq.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            stream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);   //Enviem el cos de la petició
                        }
                        body = false;
                    }
                }
                else throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");

                //Obtenim la resposta del servidor
                HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
                Stream rebut = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(rebut, Encoding.UTF8); // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
                string info = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                if (tipus == 0) jsonclient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuari.Client>>(info);
                else if (tipus == 1) jsonedif = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuari.Building>>(info);
                else if (tipus == 2) jsonplanta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuari.Floor>>(info);
                else if (tipus == 3) jsonhab = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuari.Room>>(info);
                else if (tipus == 4) jsonnode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuari.Node>>(info);
            }

            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // same as normal response, get error response
                var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                string errorResponseJson;
                var statusCode = errorResponse.StatusCode;
                var errorIdFromHeader = errorResponse.GetResponseHeader("Error-Id");
                using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    errorResponseJson = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
                //var errorCode = JsonObject.Parse(errorResponseJson).Object("responseStatus")["errorCode"];
                //var errorMessage = JsonObject.Parse(errorResponseJson).Object("responseStatus")["message"];
            }
        }
```

Why I'm having this error? `List<Usuari.Node>` is an array that contains all the items of JSON message. I try to fix the error but I'm not able to find and answer. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service returns just one `Node`, instead of an array of `Node`s with one element. To solve this problem, you can use one of these approaches:

1. Change the service so it always returns an array (by wrapping the result before returning it).
2. If 1. is not an option: Differentiate the different response types in the client (check if the response is an array and if not, tell the serializer to parse a single `Node` instead of a list) and either handle the single object differently or just wrap it in a list and then proceed as if the server returned it like that.

Comment: The response is the string "info", is the first textboox that I paste. Analysing the response I think I have a node array, two node elements and each element has different items. I don't understand the first approach, how I can change the service return? Do you have  an example? Thanks

Comment: If you actually had an array, the first character would be `[`. What you have is a single `Node` with `Limit` = 10, `Offset` = 0 and two `Node_sub` objects in `nodes_sub`.